# Recibir notificaciones cuando la aplicación es cerrada(killed)

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, intentservice

Estoy haciendo una aplicación que requiere mostrar notificaciones aun cuando la aplicación haya sido cerrada(killed)
Cree un servicio el cual me funciona muy bien mientras la aplicación este activa o en segundo plano, pero al destruir la aplicación el servicio deja de funcionar.

Alguien sabe si es posible recibir notificaciones como whatsapp u otras sin tener la aplicación activa ni en segundo plano?

Este es el servicio que actualmente me funciona

```
public class MyService extends Service {
private FBService fbService;
private boolean serviceStarted = false;

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId){
    // START YOUR TASKS
    Toast.makeText(this, "Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    shpCuenta c = new shpCuenta(this);
    c = c.retrieve();
    if(!c.getFirebaseUserId().isEmpty() && !serviceStarted){
        SugarContext.init(this);
        fbService = new FBService(this);
        serviceStarted = true;
        fbService.cargaMensajeGrupos(c.getid());
    }

    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    // STOP YOUR TASKS
    Toast.makeText(this, "Service Destroyed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}
}
```

Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buenas noches, lo que te sugiero es que si deseas trabajar con notificaciones locales podrias utilizar el servicio del Alarm Manager para permitir enviar las notificaciones cuando tu app se cerro por completo, hasta te las mandaria cuando reinicias el celular y no abres la app, puedes definir el horario que quieras que aparezcan.

[Notificaciones Locales diarias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19057166/daily-local-notification-by-setting-time-android)

[Notificaciones locales con un datetime especifico](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23106006/how-schedule-local-notifications-android)

Si necesitas recibir notificaciones de acuerdo a un mensaje por medio de internet o mostrar una notificacion con valores actualizados, te recomiendo que uses el GCM (o google cloud messaging) ofrecen push notifications que sirven para este caso

https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/

Espero te sirva, y si es asi , que marques como correcta la respuesta, asi puedo seguir ayudando y me da gusto hacerlo :)

Comment: Excelente, gracias, usare GCM bueno ya Firebase Cloud Messaging.